# Generics and unchecked cast

Tags: android, generics, casting, warnings

I know this question as been asked so much time but anyway I can't find something that I can apply to my code. Maybe because I didn't fully understand everything. I just want to avoid the `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` solution. So find a new architecture for my code.

I have the warning `Unchecked cast:com.example.reader.models.SearchableBook to T` at this line when i try to cast to generic type : `(T)epubReader.readEpub(fileInputStream)`

```
public class BookHelper {
   public static <T> T openBook(String ebookFilePath, boolean searchable) {
        T book = null;
        EpubReader epubReader = new EpubReader();
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(ebookFilePath);
            book = searchable ? (T)new SearchableBook(epubReader.readEpub(fileInputStream)) : (T)epubReader.readEpub(fileInputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fileInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return book;
    }
}
```

I use generics because I want this BookHelper method can return a Book or a SearchableBook avoiding having two very similar methods.

I tried to send the type as parameter to the method doing something like this but I still have the same warning. I still have to return a generic type so for sure I have the same problem :

```
public static <T> T openBook(String ebookFilePath, boolean searchable, Type t) {
    T book = null;
    EpubReader epubReader = new EpubReader();
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(ebookFilePath);
        if(t instanceof Book) {
            book = (T)epubReader.readEpub(fileInputStream);
        } else ...
```

In this last case it's not unsafe at all so I could use the SuppressWarnings but I would like to do this the right way... and I would like to know how people generally do in this case. I guess the best method is not to replicate my code to avoid this warning...

## Update 1

Now i have my Searchable interface :

```
public interface Searchable {

    String findSentence(String words);
}
```

The wrapper MyBook that implements this interface :

```
public class MyBook implements Searchable  {
    private Book mBook;

    public MyBook(Book book) {
        this.setBook(book);
    }

    public Book getBook() {
        return mBook;
    }

    public void setBook(Book book) {
        mBook = book;
    }

    @Override
    public String findSentence(String words) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

My `openBook(String ebookFilePath, boolean searchable)` method :

```
public static MyBook openBook(String ebookFilePath, boolean searchable) {
    MyBook book = null;
    EpubReader epubReader = new EpubReader();
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

    try {
        fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(ebookFilePath);
        book = new MyBook(epubReader.readEpub(fileInputStream));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fileInputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return book;
}
```

In MainActivity :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
...  
        MyBook searchBook = BookHelper.openBook(BOOK0_PATH, true);
        Book book = BookHelper.openBook(BOOK1_PATH,false).getBook();
...    
}
```

It works, with no code replication but. If i want to instantiate a Book I just instanciate the wrapper and call the getter `getBook()`. But then what happen to the ressources used to instanciate `MyBook` that I don't need for a `Book` ? I'm talking about the resource used by the implementation of search capabilities => `findSentence()` that are specific to a searchable book (MyBook wrapper).  Are they used only in my `OpenBook` method and the GC clear them after ? . In fact It looks so simple that I don't understand why I didn't think about it earlier...

but then, what is the goal of the interface ? because clearly I don't really need it as there will be several methods in the MyBook class and no one is mandatory, so don't need to put in an interface. Hope i'm clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about if you define something like this:

`public static <T extends Book> T openBook(String ebookFilePath, boolean searchable)`

**Update:**

Create a wrapper `MyBook` which includes `Book` as a field. Then create an interface `Searchable` and implement it in `MyBook`. Then you can remove the generic:

`public static MyBook openBook(String ebookFilePath, boolean searchable)`

Create getter and setter for the field `Book`.

Comment: So my generic type will inherit from Book. How is this supposed to work ? I can't cast SearchableBook to T if T extends Book.

Comment: Well i thought `SearchableBook` extends `Book`... If not i would recommend using an interface instead of generic type.

Comment: Ok, so if I use `public static <T extends Book> T openBook(String ebookFilePath, boolean searchable)` and `SearchableBook` extends `Book` that should work ?

Comment: It doesn't work. It says me `required T found Book` even with `public static <T extends Book> T openBook(String ebookFilePath, boolean searchable)`. If I cast to T I have the warning.

Comment: If I use an interface then I have to implement the code twice with a different implementation for Ebook and SearchableBook. I can't modify Ebook, it's from an external library. Or maybe I didn't understand something.

Comment: Updated my question with the new code. Anyway it's not so clean to me to have to do this : `Book book = BookHelper.openBook(BOOK1_PATH,false).getBook();`. I would prefer my openBook method return me a Book or a searchable Book without having to use the getter.

Comment: To ask your question about what is the goal: You don't have redundant implementations. You always work with `MyBook`. This class always implements the search function. So in other words you always work with a searchable book. If you add another field `searchable` to `MyBook`  you can control this ability. If you don't want that this `MyBook` instance is searchable, then pass `false` to the constructor. Don't forget to create getter + setter for this field. You can add an additional check in `findSentence` for this ability.

Answer (score 0):

make it a checked exception: void f() throws IllegalArgumentExceprion;

Comment: `public static <T> T openBook(String ebookFilePath, boolean searchable) throws IllegalArgumentException { ... }` still have the warning.

Answer (score 0):

I finally changed my architecture.

I wanted to use this `Ebook` class from [Epublib](http://www.siegmann.nl/epublib) and add to it the ability to search in the book to find a sentence containing specific words so that was the purpose of my SearchableBook class.

```
import nl.siegmann.epublib.domain.Book;

public class SearchableBook {
    private Book mBook;

    // Find a sentence containing the words in parameters
    public Sentence findSentence(String[] wordsToFind) { ... }

    ...
}
```

First I tried to extends the Epublib Book class but then realized I can't cast a Book to a SearchableBook and this was a problem for me regarding my plans. So I tried this other approach I explained in this topic. Creating a SearchableBook class that not extends Book but have a Book as a property and a BookHelper class to avoid the replication of this :

```
EpubReader epubReader = new EpubReader();
FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

try {
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(ebookFilePath);
    book = epubReader.readEpub(fileInputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
        fileInputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

To be able to use this code for `Book` and `SearchableBook` class I tried (as described in my question) to do this in my BookHelper class :

```
 public static <T> T openBook(String ebookFilePath, boolean searchable) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        T book = null;
        EpubReader epubReader = new EpubReader();
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

        try {
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(ebookFilePath);
            book = searchable ? (T)new SearchableBook(epubReader.readEpub(fileInputStream)) : (T)epubReader.readEpub(fileInputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                fileInputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return book;
    }
```

But got the Unchecked cast issue.

I then tried to use an `Interface` :

```
public interface BookBehaviour { Object read(String ebookFilePath); }
```

But then I had to implement this read method in my `SearchableBook` class, need to add another class for my not searchable Book to be able to implement the read method in it... so I came back to my first problem, replication.

Finally I went back to an easier approach. No more inheritance, interface, generics or reflection... just created a `BookHelper` class that receives a `Book` as parameter and implements the search capabilities. Then I can instanciate two Book, one will use my `BookHelper` class and the other one not. This BookHelper class will contains a method to open the book too and avoid the replication of the `InputStream` code.

I just wanted to use these more complex things because I see everybody use in their projects... but just realize I should continue to do without because even if i start to understand the concepts and read tons about it I never really need these things in my project, like in this particular one.

Anyway if you have better proposition so have a better answer to this question you're welcome.

Answer (score -1):

Have you thought about creating an Interface instead of using generics? This way both your Book or a SearchableBook could implement it and your cast would not be a problem.

Edit:

Actually there is no logic in using generics at all, you could change your generics to an interface like this: `public interface BookBehaviour { Object readEpub(FileInputStream fileInputStream); }` Then your class SearchableBook should implement BookBehaviour and also your method readEpub(fileInputStream) should return the BookBehaviour type.

Comment: So ? if I understand good then I have my Book and SearchableBook classes implements BookBehaviour. Then I'll have to implement readEpub() method for each class then my code is still replicated, isn't it ?